# How to implement errors handling in custom kafka connector

Tags: apache-kafka, error-handling, apache-kafka-connect

I have created some custom kafka sink connector i want to use error handling capability in it but when I am trying erros.tolerance=all still my connector is failing I am throwing ConnectException.

My connector is failing regardless of error configuration.

Can someone please guide me do I have to use any interface to add error handling capability in my custom kafka connector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`errors.tolerance` is not a pluggable interface for Connect Framework. It is an `enum` with only a few options.

You need to throw `RetriableException` for transient errors, but the connector will still fail when retries are exhausted.